# Logs for CPU/GPU scaling

Tags: google-cloud-ml

How can we see complete logs for GPU/CPU scaling on Vertex AI? I want to see all the details about how Vertex AI is doing auto-scaling. How can I see the complete logs?

Comment: Did you check [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging)? Could you provide more details about your env and scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will have complete logs for `GPU/CPU` scaling on `Vertex AI`. Currently it supports 2 kinds of [Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services) like:

- [Admin Activity audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#admin-activity)

> Google Cloud services write audit logs to help you answer the questions, "Who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud resources.

It's about who make some changes.

- [Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#data-access)

> Data Access audit logs contain API calls that read the configuration or metadata of resources, as well as user-driven API calls that create, modify, or read user-provided resource data.

It's more about data not resources.

The closes logs which can you get in `Vertex AI` is described in:

[Online prediction logging](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging#enable_disable_logs-console) which provides

- `Container logging`, which logs the stdout and stderr streams from your prediction nodes to Cloud Logging. These logs are essential and required for debugging.
- `Access logging`, which logs information like timestamp and latency for each request to Cloud Logging.

or

[Cloud Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/monitoring-metrics) which provides `CPU/GPU/Memory` usage or `Network usage`.

Currently those are the available options for `Vertex AI`. I don't think that you will be able to see `GPU/CPU` scaling like in `Computer Engine` logs.